# how to convert UTC timezone DateTime in to local timezone using Django ORM query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-timezone

```
class Book(models.Model):

    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

this datetime is in utc timezone and I want to this datetime in to local timezone converted using query.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `pytz` for this.

First, find your timezone from `pytz.all_timezones` (ex: `Asia/Kolkata`)

```
import pytz
book_obj = Book.objects.get(pk=1)  # Replace query parameters according to your needs
my_timezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata") # Replace Asia/Kolkata with your timezone
local_created_at = book_obj.created_at.astimezone(my_timezone)
```